# Is it bad practice to use a global function inside a class ?

Tags: php, class, function, model-view-controller, global

Question about using global functions inside classes, I'm working on a MVC system.

The following method is part of a class it calls methods in the class such as the model and the view my question is I've got a global function in there called redirect() I've set it in a functions file that's loaded in my bootstrap file, as all controllers may need access to it, is this a bad practice or would I be best to make this a method of the controller class as all the controllers extend the parent controller.

```
public function post($slug){

  if(!$slug){ redirect('blog'); }

  $data = $this->model->getPost($slug);
  $this->view->render('blog/single', $data);
}
```

Or would a static class make more sense? just seems a little over the top for a simple redirect function.

Comment: I was thinking a class with static a method just seems too much for a tiny method.

Comment: is it just a header location?

Comment: yes its:

    function redirect($url){
 header('location: '.DIR.$url);
 exit;
    }

Comment: @Dave: Although if you had a static class that contained global methods then presumably your `redirect()` method would not be the only method of that class?

Comment: as it currently stands it would although I do have a slug function as well..

Comment: do you access your bootstrap from controller?

Comment: no the bootstrap loads the requested controller/method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Global functions are not necessarily bad practice. There are two things to be aware of:

**Naming:** You should make sure that the name of the function avoids collisions and is obvious to what it relates. Your redirect function, it would be expected that it performs a request redirect. If instead your method related to something else more specific it would need to be clear that that is the case by prepending some contextual information.

**State:** Global functions should be stateless. This means the function should always provide the same result for the given input. If it does different things depending upon the time of day, the value of some variable, etc... Then generally this is bad. That may see like an obvious pitfall but there are more subtle versions of that problem. The obvious exception to this rule is actually requesting the time of day...

It looks like your code there obeys these two rules and so it is perfectly acceptable to do this.

**Edit** There is the **testability** issue, as you are referencing a global function that is required in by the class (or should be), you cannot mock this. For example in your redirect example you couldn't test the class properly without triggering the redirect function and you can't use a mock version of the function to detect that the real redirect method would have been called.

Comment: that's true but as its a simple function I'm happy with that.

Answer (score 2):

Using  global function is bad practice, because it makes your classes untestable. You should put your desired methods to some object and pass it to classes as their dependency.

Comment: as that makes sense I think it this case the main controller would be the best place for it.

My inital thought that a view may need it, also I've noticed code igniter uses global functions for redirects and the base_url

Answer (score 1):

As you indicate in the comments it is a tiny one liner method, if you use PHP 5.3, rather than global would be better to use a lambda function and pass it in rather than create a whole new class.

I would try and design to code so dependencies are injected and maybe expose the bootstrap to the controller and store a lambda in there then just call it where you want.

See http://fabien.potencier.org/article/17/on-php-5-3-lambda-functions-and-closures for lambda use, the DI example will also offer some insight hopefully.